# Passing a string as parameter in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am trying to make a library system using C++, where i would ask the user for input for book name, author, and year and it will be stored in a linked list. I have done the following so far in the header file (which seems to have no errors)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "LinkedList.h"
using namespace std;

class LinkedList {

private:

struct BookNode {
    string Book_Title;
    string Author_Name;
    int Year_of_Publishing ;
    BookNode* next;
};
public:

LinkedList();
void addInfo(string,string, int);
void print();
};
```

and for the .cpp

```
void LinkedList::addInfo(string data1,string data2, int data3)
{
BookNode* n = new BookNode;
n->Book_Title = data1;
n->Author_Name = data2;
n->Year_of_Publishing = data3;
n->next = NULL;
curr = head;
```

However, for this its giving the error

> `LinkedList::addInfo(<error-type>, <error-type>, int)`" (declared at line 27 of

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: 1. Did you `#include <string>`? 2. Did you `using namespace std;`?

Comment: It is better to pass them as const references i.e. `addInfo(const string& data1,const string& data2, int data3)` saves on the copying

Comment: Using `using std` is a [bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Would you add the complete error message?

Comment: Are you self-including your header? That can't be good.

Comment: Never ever do using namespace in a header file.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `string` as parameter type in the header you need to do two things:

- The header must have `#include <string>`
- Replace `string` with `std::string`, or add `using namespace std` (not recommended)

```
#include <string>

class LinkedList {
...
    void addInfo(std::string, std::string, int);
};
```

Comment: I did both of them. And why isnt using namespace std not recommended?

Comment: Or add `using std::string;` (not as bad as `using namespace std` but still...)

Comment: @MuneebRehman using namespace "dumps" the content of the entire namespace into global scope. This may conflict with names in your own program, now or in the future.